# Matplotlib multicoloredline using lists and an external property as condition

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I have 3 lists that all have same number of elements:

```
time_list ###(float - converted from date object with matplotlib.dates.date2num) 

temperature_list ###(float)

heating_list ###(boolean)
```

I want to plot the temperature as a function of time using Matplotlib. I also have the list heating_list that consists of boolean values True/False depending on if there was heating occuring at that time. I want the curve to be for example red if it is being heated, and blue if it is not.

I did find this example: http://wiki.scipy.org/Cookbook/Matplotlib/MulticoloredLine

However, I would like  to use heating_list to decide the color instead of some temperature values. I would also like to use the lists I already have, rather than numpy arrays as in the example.

EDIT:

What have I tried.

```
colors = ListedColormap(["b", "k"])
norm = BoundaryNorm([not heating, heating], colors.N) ### I don't really know how to define this condition
lc = LineCollection(tuple(zip(time_list, temperature_list)), label = "T1", cmap=colors, norm=norm)
###I tried to make my lists the same form as this "linen = (x0, y0), (x1, y1), ... (xm, ym)"
###According to LineCollection found here: http://matplotlib.org/api/collections_api.html

plt.gca().add_collection(lc)
plt.show()
```

I also tried:

```
   time_plot = plt.plot(time_list, temperature_list, label = "T1")
   time_plot.gca().add_collection(lc)
```

There were some problems that my lists were in a wrong format and thats why I tried to do all those zip/tuple things. Then I realized that it couldn't work anyway, because I don't know how to define when to have which colors. The cookbook example simply defined ranges for the values, whereas I don't want it to be dependant on temperature values, but instead an external property.

Comment: What have you tried?  That cookbook page is defiantly what you want, so where are you having trouble adapting it?  As you question currently stands it reads as 'please do my work for me' which annoys many people (myself included) and greatly reduces the number of people who will answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

I eventually did this by plotting several plots so that each plot would always be one color. However, this leaves small gaps between plots and you can't easily handle it as one plot.

I found out it's also much easier to do this kind of thing with scatters if you don't need to connect the dots, because scatter can have a colormap as an argument.